# Accessing CRC (OpenShift) on a remote server: "openshift crc ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused"

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, openshift, crc

I ask you for help because I was unable to access the OpenShift web console, installed in a VM, from my pc.

I am not an expert on linux, so please excuse me if I make any mistakes in exposing the problem.

I followed these steps:

1. I accessed the shell of the VM via SSH.
2. I successfully installed CRC on VM following this guide: https://crc.dev/crc/#installation_gsg.
3. I added at the end of my computer's etc/hosts file the following line: `127.0.0.1 oauth-openshift.apps-crc.testing console-openshift-console.apps-crc.testing downloads-openshift-console.apps-crc.testing default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps-crc.testing canary-openshift-ingress-canary.apps-crc.testing`
4. I tried to access the web console of Openshift via SSH with this command: `ssh -L 443:console-openshift-console.apps-crc.testing:443 myuser@xxx.xx.x.xxx`

But I got the following error message: `ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused`.
If it helps, by running the same command with `-v` flag, I get: `debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files`

What could be the problem? Did I do something wrong or did I forget any configuration to do?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You said that in step 1 you are able to successfully access your VM via ssh, but in step 4 you are now getting an error when attempting to connect to the same machine?

Comment: @larsks yes, I used two different commands: in the step 1 I used `ssh myuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 8822` and it didn't give me any problems (I was able to install CRC); in the step 4 I used the command I wrote above to access the web console of OpenShift, but I got that error message.

Comment: My goal is to access the openshift console from my pc (without opening any ports, as explained in the documentation).

Comment: Sorry, in step 3 the address isn't `127.0.0.1`, but `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`. However, I still get the same error.

Comment: It’s not really designed to be used this way. I’ve heard of people hacking some proxies in, but you are basically trying to do something (accessing it remotely) it’s specifically designed not to do. If you want to treat it like a dev server rather than a workstation, you should probably use SNO.